# Cannot find Intel Q965/Q963 graphics driver

Tags: windows-8, drivers, display, intel-graphics

I need to install graphics driver for Windows 8 64 bit PC. When I load Win7 64 bit on the same PC, I see the following information in Device Manager, Display adapters: Intel Q965/Q963 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.0). I believe that this driver can work in Windows 8, but I cannot find this driver download in the Intel site - it only shows Q965/Q963 drivers for Windows XP.

Where can I find Win7 64 bit driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your motherboard does not appear to be fully Windows 7 compatible and the driver you are using in Windows 7 is one that was shipped with Windows.

Upon doing research, the newest version I can find is from Windows Vista, [located here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=17345&lang=eng&OSVersion=%0A&DownloadType=Drivers).

All I can suggest for you is that you hope Microsoft will again release a legacy driver inside Windows 8 RTM, but, unfortunately nothing can be guaranteed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this driver cannot be installed on Windows 8. It looks like I need to find some supported display adapter instead of on-board Intel adapter. Thanks.